# Are these codes(concurrent C codes) necessary to use memory barrier?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, concurrency, memory-barriers

1. I found these codes in project libuv 1.3.0. But I can't understand that why memory barriers(for compiler) are need.

   ```
   static int uv__async_make_pending(int* pending) {
     /* Do a cheap read first. */
     if (ACCESS_ONCE(int, *pending) != 0)
       return 1;

     /* Micro-optimization: use atomic memory operations to detect if we've been
      * preempted by another thread and don't have to make an expensive syscall.
      * This speeds up the heavily contended case by about 1-2% and has little
      * if any impact on the non-contended case.
      *
      * Use XCHG instead of the CMPXCHG that __sync_val_compare_and_swap() emits
      * on x86, it's about 4x faster. It probably makes zero difference in the
      * grand scheme of things but I'm OCD enough not to let this one pass.
      */
   #if defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__)
     {
       unsigned int val = 1;
       __asm__ __volatile__ ("xchgl %0, %1"
                            : "+r" (val)
                            : "m"  (*pending));
       return val != 0;
     }
   #elif defined(__GNUC__) && (__GNUC__ > 4 || __GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 0)
     return __sync_val_compare_and_swap(pending, 0, 1) != 0;
   #else
     ACCESS_ONCE(int, *pending) = 1;
     return 0;
   #endif
   }
   ```
2. We can simplify these codes by different environments. For x86:

   ```
   static int uv__async_make_pending(int* pending) {
     if (ACCESS_ONCE(int, *pending) != 0)
       return 1;

     {
       unsigned int val = 1;
       __asm__ __volatile__ ("xchgl %0, %1"
                            : "+r" (val)
                            : "m"  (*pending));
       return val != 0;
     }
   }
   ```

   For GNU C 4:

   ```
   static int uv__async_make_pending(int* pending) {
     if (ACCESS_ONCE(int, *pending) != 0)
       return 1;

     return __sync_val_compare_and_swap(pending, 0, 1) != 0;
   }
   ```

   For others:

   ```
   static int uv__async_make_pending(int* pending) {
     if (ACCESS_ONCE(int, *pending) != 0)
       return 1;

     ACCESS_ONCE(int, *pending) = 1;
     return 0;
   }
   ```
3. I use the last one as a example. If I remove memory barriers for it:

   ```
   static int uv__async_make_pending(int* pending) {
     if (*pending != 0)
       return 1;

     *pending = 1;
     return 0;
   }
   ```

   Will the above codes do the wrong thing after compiled by gcc? I can't figure out what optimizations will be done by gcc.
4. I have google the codes directly, but there is no result to explain why memory barriers are necessary.
5. I have google the memory barriers, but there is no result to explain when I need to use memory barriers for specific codes. I understand what memory barriers are.
6. I have goole the lock free programming in C language, but there is no result to explain how codes will be optimized by compiler.

Comment: If your code is sequential, then I do not expect memory barrier to be useful. If your code is parallel, then they are required for other threads (possibly on other cores) to see the impact of the code in the current thread in a correct order. Volatile operation ensure the value is read/write from/to memory and not just stored in a register (i.e. not visible from other threads). Volatile+Barriers is still not atomic so it should not be used for other thing than booleans (or without using another sync mechanism). Otherwise, atomics is the way to go. In fact, it is also safer for boolean.

Comment: Put it shortly : your code is wrong if there are multiple threads (UB due to a race condition) and it needs to be protected with atomics if so.

Comment: You could look yourself how it gets optimized by a compiler, although you'd have to look at how it inlines into a caller because the function boundary is enough to force memory access.  ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) / https://godbolt.org/).  And/or read about what problems to look for in [Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler?](https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/), and that's just about accesses happening exactly one or not, without worrying about ordering wrt. other operations like @JérômeRichard mentioned.

Comment: That libuv code is definitely from the dark ages of lock-free programming, before we could just use C11 `atomic_compare_exchange_strong` or `tmp = atomic_exchange_explicit(pending, 1, memory_order_release)`.  (The existing implementation is portable to non-x86, and can return without doing an acquire load, just a `volatile` load which is like `memory_order_relaxed`. Unless it's different when the old value was `0`, perhaps.) Or in GNU C (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html), `__atomic_exchange_n(pending, 1, __ATOMIC_RELEASE)` with still `int *`, not `_Atomic int*`

Comment: And just for the record, I don't see any reason why `lock cmpxchg` / `test/jcc` (`__sync_val_compare_and_swap`) would be 4x slower than `xchg` / `test/jcc` on any x86.  It might be a tiny bit faster and smaller code size, but `xchg` with memory is still slow even on ancient in-order P5.

Comment: Oh, also, the comments talk about making a system call depending on the result of the call.  If you don't do an atomic exchange or CAS to make sure you know the old value before you make it `1`, you'd have to unconditionally do the system call (presumably to wake up any other threads that might be waiting).  Missing a wakeup can lead to a deadlock, and that can happen if you just check read-only and then do a pure store; it leaves a window for another thread to have gone to sleep between your check and your store. That can't be repaired with barriers / ordering, only with atomicity for an RMW.

Comment: I have got the answer. It seems that this question is not worth to keep. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

@Jérôme Richard,@Peter Cordes
Thanks for your comments. I think I have figured out the question. The ACCESS_ONE(memory barrier) here is guaranteed to read from or write to memory for variable pending, instead of the register.
Because of I paid all attention to instruction reording, then lost sight of optimization about register substituting memory accessing. Going further and further in the wrong direciton. It's important that someone gives a simple hint when another one is caught in a infinite loop.

Comment: `ACCESS_ONE(T,x)` isn't a memory barrier, it doesn't enforce any *ordering*, only access.  I assume it's defined something like `*(volatile T*)&x` like how the Linux macros is.  If you want any memory barriers, you have to use inline asm.  (Or use C11 `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release)` or something, or a full barrier with legacy GNU C `__sync_synchronize()`.  Or compile-time-ordering only, `asm("" ::: "memory")` - https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/) .

Comment: But yes, something like `volatile` (or preferably `_Atomic`) is necessary here.  In fact, it's likely the atomic RMW they use is actually required, otherwise it would be a big missed optimization.